# System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object in microsoft dynamics crm 2011 web application

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics

pls reply as soon as possible..I m getting this problem in dynamics crm 2011 on premises installation.

Comment: 'please reply as soon as possible' comes across as quite rude. You are going to need a lot more information for anyone to provide an answer - when is this happening? Where? Can you show the code causing the exception?

Answer (score 0):

As glosrob mentioned more detailed info would help us give you a more accurate answer.

If you have any issues during a basic install of the CRM software, verify you have all the prerequisites installed and configured correctly.

Here's a list of the pre-reqs

http://www.dynamicscrmtrickbag.com/2011/05/15/dynamics-crm-server-2011-on-premise-hardware-and-software-requirements/